# In Flask, why does this hello world app work?

Tags: python, flask

Looking at the default "Hello world" script on Flask's website:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I'm very new to programming, so I don't understand how this script can work - the `hello()` function isn't called anywhere, so does Flask simply display the output of the first function found? What if I wanted to display outputs from two or three functions on the page?

Comment: Remember also that app.run() calls what is effectively a very simple development web server to run your script, the and app.route("/") decorator works along with the server. So to extend on what Lewis said: Flask has a great deal of code "under the hood" to make the script work, and it's not all visible in the sample script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line: `@app.route("/")` will register the function as the handler for the '/' route. When the browser queries '/' (the root), the application responds "Hello World!".

The `@` syntax is called Decorators.

[How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this code for instance:

```
def decorator(func):
    print "this function is called for " + func 
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def hello():
    return "Hello"
```

Save it into a file and try it,you'll see that after defining hello you see something like this :

> this function is called for < function hello at 0x241c70>